# Slot Machines Project

Tags: python

Hello i build project Slot Machine this project was inspired by Tech with Tim here's his code from this project how he implement that --> https://github.com/techwithtim/Python-Slot-Machine/blob/main/main.py .I changed the code of the project on my way but something is same but most of the things i tried to change to check if i understand the project well.I am looking for maybe another way to implement the structure of code and tell me if i've done something wrong , what i should do better or to add something more.

```
import random
MAX_VALUE = 100
MIN_VALUE = 1
ROWS = 3
COLUMNS = 3

symbols_count = {
    "A":2,
    "B":4,
    "C":5,
    "E":3,
    "F":2
}

symbols_values = {
    "A":2,
    "B":4,
    "C":5,
    "E":3,
    "F":2
}
def check_winnings(columns,bet_lines,bet,balance):
    first_column = []
    second_column = []
    third_columns = []
    for element in columns:
        if len(first_column) < 3:
            first_column.append(element)
        elif len(second_column) < 3:
            second_column.append(element)
        elif len(third_columns) < 3:
            third_columns.append(element)
    check_duplicates_first = set(first_column) # we make sets because if there's three characters same it will return only one but remove the two duplicates
    check_duplicates_second = set(second_column)
    check_duplicates_third = set(third_columns)

    if len(check_duplicates_first) == 1:
        print("Winning line is --> line one --<")
        balance += bet_lines * bet
        print(f"You got it this time ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)
    elif len(check_duplicates_second) == 1:
        print("Winning line is --> line two <--")
        balance += bet_lines * bet
        print(f"You got it this time ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)
    elif len(check_duplicates_third) == 1:
        print("Winning line is --> line three --<")
        balance += bet_lines * bet
        print(f"You got it this time ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)
    elif len(check_duplicates_first) > 1 or len(check_duplicates_second) > 1 or len(check_duplicates_third):
        get_sum = bet_lines * bet
        balance = balance - get_sum
        print(f"You didn't get it try again ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)




def spin_slot_machine(symbols):
    all_symbols = []
    columns = []
    length_of_spin = 9
    for symbol,symbol_count in symbols.items():
        for i in range(symbol_count):
            all_symbols.append(symbol)
    for i in range(length_of_spin):
        get_random = random.choice(all_symbols)
        columns.append(get_random)
    return columns 
def print_slot_machine(columns):
    first_row = ' | '.join(columns[0:3])
    second_row = ' | '.join(columns[3:6])
    third_row = ' | '.join(columns[6:9])
    print(first_row)
    print(second_row)
    print(third_row)






def deposit():
    while True:
        deposit_money = input("How much money would you like to deposit?: $")
        if deposit_money.isdigit():
            deposit_money = int(deposit_money)
            if deposit_money > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("You should deposit more than 0$")
        print("Enter a digit")
    return deposit_money 
def bet_on_lines():
    while True:
        lines = input("On how many lines would you like to bet(1-3)?: ")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if lines >= 1 and lines <= 3:
                break
            else:
                print("Number of lines should be between 1-3")
        print("Enter a number of lines")
    return lines


def get_bet():
    while True:
        bet = input("How much money would you like to bet on one line(1$-100$): ")
        if bet.isdigit():
            bet = int(bet)
            if bet <= MAX_VALUE and bet >= MIN_VALUE:
                break
            else:
                print("Money should be between 1-100$")
        else:
            print("Enter a digit")
    return bet 


def spin():
    balance = deposit()
    lines_number = bet_on_lines()
    while True:
        bet_money = get_bet()
        total_bet = bet_money * lines_number 
        if total_bet > balance:
            print(f"Your balance is {balance}$.Balance shoudn't be less than betting money , bet less!")
        else:
            break
    print(f"You are betting {total_bet}$ on {lines_number} lines.")
    slot_machine = spin_slot_machine(symbols_count)
    print_slot_machine(slot_machine)
    check_winnings(slot_machine,lines_number,bet_money,balance)
def playagain(balance):
    while True:
        answer = input("Do you want to play again(Press Enter or q to quit): ")
        if answer != "" or balance == 0:
            print(f"You left with {balance}$, Good Bye!")
            break
        else:
            if int(balance) > 0:
                lines_number = bet_on_lines()
                bet_money = get_bet()
                slot_machine = spin_slot_machine(symbols_count)
                print_slot_machine(slot_machine)
                check_winnings(slot_machine,lines_number,bet_money,balance)
                break





spin()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PEP-8

First off, your whitespace is all over the place. [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommendations are a set of rules to standardise the layout and appearance of Python code to make it easier for anyone who comes along to read and use it. It recommends:

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

Amongst other things. A good linter such as [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) or [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) will highlight these issues for you automatically.

`playagain` violates the "functions should be snake-case" principle.

### If-else

In your `check_winnings` function, you have your `if`-block which checks each row for whether each row's symbols are all the same and then whether they're not. The `else` block will handle that for you. If something doesn't match any of the preceding `if`s, the `else` will run, which is what you want here.

```
    #Reformatted for clarity and to highlight typo
    elif (len(check_duplicates_first) > 1 or
          len(check_duplicates_second) > 1 or 
          len(check_duplicates_third)):
```

simply becomes:

```
    else:
```

You have the inverse problem in `playagain` where you have:

```
        if answer != "" or balance == 0:
            print(f"You left with {balance}$, Good Bye!")
            break
        else:
            if int(balance) > 0:
```

Which could easily be:

```
elif int(balance) > 0:
```

However, following a `break` you needn't have the `else` at all.

### Sampling and using the right functions

Another bug comes in with the fact that you are doing several independent choices for your wheels:

```
    for i in range(length_of_spin):
        get_random = random.choice(all_symbols)
        columns.append(get_random)
```

This does not obey `symbol_counts` (as done with replacement) and in principle, it would be possible for you to roll `['A']*9`

First off, we could clean it up using a list comprehension (as in several other places)

```
    # If you don't use a loop argument, it is customary to name it _
    columns = [random.choice(all_symbols) for _ in range(length_of_spin)
```

second, we could use `random.choices` (see `help(random)`)

> ```
> choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1) method of Random instance
>     Return a k sized list of population elements chosen with replacement.
> ```

```
    columns = random.choices(all_symbols, k=length_of_spin)
```

However, noting this is **with replacement**, we should use `random.sample`, which does what we want!

```
    columns = random.sample(all_symbols, k=length_of_spin)
```

It even lets us avoid having to construct a list of all symbols:

```
    columns = random.sample(list(symbols.keys()), 
                            counts=list(symbols.values()),
                            k=length_of_spin)
```

Learning the tools can save you a lot of effort and time.

### Simplify

Python has tools for slicing and dealing with lists, this means that we can avoid a lot of busywork

```
    first_column = []
    second_column = []
    third_columns = []
    for element in columns:
        if len(first_column) < 3:
            first_column.append(element)
        elif len(second_column) < 3:
            second_column.append(element)
        elif len(third_columns) < 3:
            third_columns.append(element)
    # we make sets because if there's three characters same
    # it will return only one but remove the two duplicates
    check_duplicates_first = set(first_column)
    check_duplicates_second = set(second_column)
    check_duplicates_third = set(third_columns)
```

Constructs 3 temporary lists (in a somewhat complicated manner) and then builds a set from those lists. We can skip half of this work:

```
    first_column = columns[0:3]
    second_column = columns[3:6]
    third_column = columns[6:9]
```

In fact, since its so simple, we can just directly do:

```
    check_duplicates_first = set(columns[0:3])
    check_duplicates_second = set(columns[3:6])
    check_duplicates_third = set(columns[6:9])
```

### DRY

Don't repeat yourself (DRY) is the principle that good code should be written once. Take:

```
    if len(check_duplicates_first) == 1:
        print("Winning line is --> line one --<")
        balance += bet_lines * bet
        print(f"You got it this time ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)
    elif len(check_duplicates_second) == 1:
        print("Winning line is --> line two <--")
        balance += bet_lines * bet
        print(f"You got it this time ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)
    elif len(check_duplicates_third) == 1:
        print("Winning line is --> line three --<")
        balance += bet_lines * bet
        print(f"You got it this time ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)
    elif len(check_duplicates_first) > 1 or len(check_duplicates_second) > 1 or len(check_duplicates_third):
        get_sum = bet_lines * bet
        balance = balance - get_sum
        print(f"You didn't get it try again ,now you have {balance}$")
        playagain(balance)
```

For each of the winning statements, the only line which changes is the winning line, and even the lose statement computes the total spent and calls `playagain` (**N.B.** Really, we don't actually want this function calling `playagain`, that results in nested recursion, the top level should call it, but that's another issue). We could instead (and still not the most concise, but simpler):

```
    winner = None
    if len(check_duplicates_first) == 1:
        winner = "one"
    elif len(check_duplicates_second) == 1:
        winner = "two"
    elif len(check_duplicates_third) == 1:
        winner = "three"

    get_sum = bet_lines * bet
    if winner:
        balance += get_sum
        print(f"Winning line is --> line {winner} --<")
        print(f"You got it this time, now you have {balance}$")
    else:
        balance -= get_sum
        print(f"You didn't get it try again, now you have {balance}$")

    playagain(balance)
```

Likewise, you could define a single function to handle user input to replace `deposit`, `bet_on_lines` and `get_bet` all of which request an integer in a given range from a user, with a certain prompt.

Something like:

```
def get_int(prompt, min_val=None, max_val=None):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)
        if val.isdigit():
            val = int(val)
            if min_val <= val <= max_val:
                break
        # It'll show a bit oddly when either is not entered, but for now it'll do
        print(f"Val must be between {min_val}-{max_val}")
    return val
```

Similarly you reduplicate a lot of effort converting your linear list of `columns` into the `ROWSxCOLS` array which you could easily do once and make your functions work with lists of lists or arrays.

### Unused variables

`ROWS`, `COLUMNS` and `symbols_values` all seem to be unused, but could be useful. You could use `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` to compute the slice lengths, number of slices (using lists of sets rather than separate variables).

`symbols_values` was presumably originally intended to be a multiplier on the reward received.

### Summary

Putting all of the above together, you might end up with something like (adding docstring and main guard)

```
"""
Play a slot machine game
"""

import random

MAX_VALUE = 100
MIN_VALUE = 1
ROWS = 3
COLUMNS = 3

# It should be noted that using these counts it is impossible for
# A or F to win, and others are very unlikely
# Probably want to increase the count a little
SYMBOLS_COUNT = {
    "A": 2,
    "B": 4,
    "C": 5,
    "E": 3,
    "F": 2
}

SYMBOLS_VALUES = {
    "A": 2,
    "B": 4,
    "C": 5,
    "E": 3,
    "F": 2
}


def check_winnings(columns, bet_lines, bet, balance):
    """ Compute winnings based on columns """
    # Can do this because we pass columns around as a list of lists
    sets = [set(x) for x in columns[1:bet_lines]]

    # Allow multiple winners
    winners = [(i, symb[0]) for i, symb in enumerate(sets) if len(symb) == 1]

    winnings = 0
    if winners:  # Check against empty list
        for line, symb in winners:
            print("Line {line} won with {symb}")
            # Use symbols values as multiplier on returns
            # Diminishing returns for more lines
            winnings += SYMBOLS_VALUES[symb] * bet
        print(f"You won ${winnings}.")
    else:
        print("You didn't get any winners.")

    return winnings


def spin_slot_machine(symbols, rows=ROWS, cols=COLUMNS):
    """ Return set of wheels from slot machine """
    spin = random.sample(list(symbols.keys()),
                         counts=list(symbols.values()),
                         k=rows*cols)
    wheels = [spin[rows*i:rows*i+cols] for i in range(rows)]
    return wheels


def print_slot_machine(columns):
    """ Display slot machine to user """
    print("\n".join(" | ".join(col) for col in columns))


def get_int(prompt, min_val=None, max_val=None):
    """ Get an integer from a user within given bounds """
    while True:
        val = input(f"{prompt} ({min_val}-{max_val})? ")
        if val.isdigit():
            val = int(val)
            if min_val <= val <= max_val:
                break
        print(f"Invalid option {val}: must be an integer between {min_val}-{max_val}")
    return val


def get_bet(balance, cols):
    """ Get the user's bet """
    while True:
        lines_number = get_int("On how many lines would you like to bet, total bet is lines*bet",
                               1, cols)
        bet_money = get_int("How much money would you like to bet per line",
                            MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE)
        total_bet = bet_money * lines_number

        if total_bet <= balance:
            return bet_money, lines_number

        print(f"Your balance is {balance}$. You cannot afford this bet, bet less!")


def play_round(balance, rows=ROWS, cols=COLUMNS):
    """ Play a single round of slots """
    bet_money, lines_number = get_bet(balance, cols)

    print(f"You are betting {bet_money}$ on {lines_number} lines.")

    balance -= lines_number * bet_money

    slot_machine = spin_slot_machine(SYMBOLS_COUNT, rows, cols)
    print_slot_machine(slot_machine)

    balance += check_winnings(slot_machine, lines_number, bet_money, balance)

    return balance


def play_game(rows=ROWS, cols=COLUMNS):
    """ Play multiple rounds until bank exhausted or user exits """
    balance = get_int("How much starting money do you wish to have", 10, 1_000_000)
    play = True
    while play:
        balance = play_round(balance, rows, cols)
        print(f"Balance now sits at {balance}$.")
        if balance <= 0:
            print(f"You left with {balance}$, Good Bye!")
            break

        while True:
            answer = input(
                "Do you want to play again (Press 'y' to play again or 'q' to quit): ").lower()
            if answer == "y":
                play = True
                break
            if answer == "q":
                print(f"You left with {balance}$, Good Bye!")
                play = False
                break
            print(f"Invalid option {answer}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_game()
```

Some other extensions you may wish to add include the fact that real slot machines have a set of wheels, rather than random sequences. You might want to generate these wheels in advance and simulate spinning them (index into a point, and getting the next `COLUMNS` values in the sequence).

Comment: Thank you a lot , but did my code was good because i am begginer-intermediate i tried my best or should looking more for optimizating.

Comment: Your code is fine, it does most of what you set out to do. Optimisation is rarely a concern, particularly at this stage. Get it right, then get it fast IF needed. More important is that it does the job it set out to do in a comprehensible and clear way, that way someone else can come along and get it faster if they need to, or make it suit their needs.